# Angular2 and RxJS : Replace Observable Response by another Observable Response using Map

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I am extending the Angular Http Object to handle a status code globally.

If this status is 201, the Response Object contains a new token for the authentication and, as it does not contains the results expected by the component which has subscribe to the request, it also contains everything to make this request again.

Basically, I follow these scheme (in the Http extending class) :

```
return request(url, options).map((res: Response) => {
    if (res.status === 201) {
        this._authService.updateAuth(res.token);

        const newRequest = this.createNewRequest(res); // returns an Observable<Response> created with the Http.get or Http.post method

        newRequest.map((res2: Response) => {
            return res2; // I want res2 to replace res through the first map, but there is a scope problem
        });
    } else {
        return res; // In non 201 case I keep the first response (res)
    }
});
```

The problem is that because of the scope I don't know how to return res2 in the first map so the response returned to the subscriber is the one it expects.

The request is successfully launched and the server returns 200 so everything is fine, but the subscriber doesn't receive the response back.

Comment: what is the return type of createNewRequest?

Comment: This is an Observable<Response> (basically a get or a post request).

Comment: the answer of @atomrc is what I had in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to flatten the stream in order to get the second response in the main stream. 
As the non 201 response will also be flatten, you will need to wrap it inside an observable.

Here is what your code will look like:

```
return request(url, options).mergeMap((res: Response) => {
    if (res.status === 201) { 
        return this.createNewRequest(res); // returning the new request's stream
    } else {
        return Rx.Observable.of(res); // wrapped inside an observable
    }
});
```

The important parts are the `mergeMap` instead of `map` and the wrapping in `Rx.Observable.of`

Comment: I would recommend to use of as static method by importing it and use mergeMap instead of its alias (flatMap)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo humm indeed nice suggestion for the `mergeMap` :) I am not sure what you mean by using `of` as static? It is already static on `Observable` isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but you can import the method itself by using import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

Comment: Oh, I see. What is the exact benefits of using it this way? Is it for tree-shaking optimizations?

Comment: Exactly, bundle size related. Normally if you are concerned about the size of the scripts bundle you would import the rxjs operators individually. For example for mergeMap you would import the operator by using import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly.
RxJS is really powerful but not so  easy to undersand at first glance :)

(I also took your improvements @Jota.Toledo, thanks)

Comment: Excellent :) Thanks for the precisions! Concerning `mergeMap` are you sure there is a static version of it? I can't seem to find it in the docs http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: I only meant the static version of 'of' :D. There is no static method for mergeMap, cause its always invoked by an observable instance. Yeah rxjs can be tricky sometimes, but its worth the headache. Another option to see good explained examples is https://www.learnrxjs.io/